# How to detect .NET 4 from ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I have a web server that is run by a third party.  I don't have direct access to the server but I can deploy ASP.NET code to it.  I want to detect if that server is running ASP.NET 4 / .NET 4 or not.  What is the easiest way to do that?  Is there an environmental property somewhere that would tell me?  Or should I try to load a particular class that only exists in .NET 4?

Comment: How's about just asking the third party?

Comment: You'd think that would be easy, wouldn't you?  But I have reason to not trust anything they tell me. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about printing [System.Environment.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx)?

Comment: That seems to work.  I created a stand-alone test page with a <%= System.Environment.Version %> in it.  My only question is, let's say I put that in a folder alongside an existing application with a web.config that was for .NET 3.5.  What version would it show?

Comment: Nevermind that was a stupid question.  It would show whatever version of ASP.NET that IIS virtual folder is configured as.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.version.aspx